# Unable to open the service 'Tomcat7'

Tags: apache, tomcat7

Hi I installed **Apache Tomcat 7** through windows installer.And just restarted my system and Im getting the Error

> Application System Error Access is denied. Unable to open the service
>   'Tomcat7'

Comment: You probably need to add credentials with admin rights to start the service.

Comment: I think it sould be migrated to [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow these simple steps for the easy solution.

1).Use **tomcat7w.exe** to always start as an administrator.

2).Right click on the **tomcat7w.exe** which is in **'bin'** folder of the tomcat installation.

3).Select *'Properties', then in `'Compatibility'` tab under 'Privilege Level'*.

4).Select '`Run this program as an administrator`'.

Hope this helps thanks.

Answer (score 22):

1) go to the bin folder of your tomcat and run the following command through command line :

> service.bat install

you will see the message "tomcat7 service installed"

2) now run tomcat7w.exe through the command line and it should run successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem with Tomcat 8 and I've found answer:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services

You need to execute from promt:

```
cd %CATALINA_BASE% -> CATALINA_BASE : C:\Program Files\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5\bin
service.bat install
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have install tomcat previously and removed it.That is why you are getting this problem.Well,in this case change the port no from default 8080 to other by going in server.xml present in lib.Hope this will work.....

Regards,
Rohit Chaubey

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be related to the Windows User Access Control (UAC) preventing the Tomcat Service Manager from kicking off.  I ran into this issue with Tomcat 6 on Windows Server 2012, even though I installed using "Run as administrator".  I was able to eliminate the error popup on startup by following the steps already outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128026/684617).  *However, the Service Manager icon was not appearing in the Task Tray when I logged in*.

Try the following work around to get the Service Manager to start.  Unfortunately, I was only able to get it to work for my user account, not for all users who log in.  Also, I've only tested this in Windows Server 2012.  Please leave a comment if you get it working in another environment (Windows 7, Windows 8, etc.).

1. Open **Task Scheduler** and create a privileged, on demand task as described [in this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac).

   - On the **General tab**, take note of the Name you give the task, as it'll be important later (using `foo` in this example).
   - On the **Actions tab**:

     - Browse for the `Tomcat7w.exe` (or whatever the appropriate version/filename is for the service manager) in your `CATALINA_HOME/bin` directory.
     - Set "Add arguments" to `//MS//Tomcat7` (replace Tomcat7 with whatever your Tomcat service is named if it's a different name/version).
2. Open your **Startup folder** (Run `shell:startup`) and create a new Shortcut:

   - For the location of the item, type `schtasks /run /TN "foo"` where `foo` is the name you gave to the Task when you created it.
3. Restart and hopefully you'll get no error ([if you followed the already provided instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128026/684617)) and  have the Tomcat Service Manager displaying in your task tray.