# crystal server 2013 installation on windows server 2008 64bit

Tags: business-objects, crystal-reports-server

When I run Tomcat configuration I get the error below.

```
Unable to open service BOEX140Tomcat.
```

Here is the error I get when I run SAP Crystal Server management

[image]

Here are the installed components of Crystal Report Server:

[image]

I would like to know what other software and components I need to install or what configuration changes I need to make .

apache tomcat for bi 4 automatically stop it self
[enter image description here][3]

and changed the config file inside tomcat to below

the apacha bi for tomcat services automatically get stopped in Central Configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

From your first screenshot, it appears that IIS is active on port 8080. If Tomcat has been installed along with Crystal Reports server and you've used the default port settings during the installation, then Tomcat will be configured to use port 8080 as well.

Only one process can bind to a given port. So as port 8080 is taken by IIS, Tomcat will stop and exit with an error. You can probably find the error message in one of the log files (check the `log` subfolder in the Tomcat installation folder).

Here's what you can do. Either:

- Change the port Tomcat is using (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758356/3165737)).
- Change the port IIS is using (as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149605)).
- Stop the IIS service if you don't need it (as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/236223/disable-iis-service-on-windows-server-2008))..

Comment: thanks for your reply , i changed the services , disabled the ports also. didn;t work

Comment: Please edit your original post and update it with the configuration of your Tomcat, IIS and the error log contents of Tomcat.

Comment: This might help in terms of adding credentials or running as administrator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028274/unable-to-open-the-service-tomcat7